# Find largest small prime factor

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, divisibility, prime-factorization

> Let $\mathcal{Q}=19^5+660^5+1316^5$ . We know that $25$ is a factor of $\mathcal{Q}$ . Find with a proof the largest prime factor of $\mathcal{Q}$ not exceeding of $10,000$.

I found by computer search that the answer is $19$ but would like to see a more mathematical proof.

Comment: the correct answer is twelve digits long!!  Good luck even showing that that factor is prime without a computer.

Comment: Please read the question correctly , @lulu    The question asks for a prime that is at max 4 digits long .

Comment: yeah, but still, what is your own approach? Someone might come along and find a really complicated (in your eyes) or elegant (in their eyes) proof, and then you're none the wiser...

Comment: @lulu: A number not exceeding 10000 being 12 digits long?

Comment: Hi @John, it's usually a good idea to let us know what you've done in trying to solve this problem so far and where you're stuck. 
You're also likely to get better answers if you avoid the imperative

Comment: first factor 660 and 1316 into prime numbers

Comment: I missed the cap on the factor.  So, yes, the correct answer is quite small...mainly because the thing has a huge prime factor.  Like I say, I don't see an easy way to split up (or fail to split up) that giant factor.

Comment: This is an old Crux problem, however it had also the fact that there are only 48 divisors mentioned. With that tidbit, this is fairly easy to solve...

Answer (score 3):

$660+1316$ divided by 19.

I hope it will help.

We know that $a^5+b^5=(a+b)(a^4-a^3b+a^2b^2-ab^3+b^4)$.

Thus, our number divided by $19$.

By the same we we can get that our number divided by $7$ and by $3$,

but it's not so relevant here.

Comment: Sir , I have used a computer to find that 19 is that prime  , but I am unable to find a mathematical proof for it .

Comment: @John We can understand it without computer. I added something. See now, please.

Comment: Sir, how can we prove that there are no primes in (20 to10,000) that divide Q  ?

Comment: @John  I think, this is a big problem here!

Comment: Let $q$ be a prime which divides the sum, write $r,s,t$ for $19,660,1316$ mod $q$, then you have that $r^5+s^5+t^5 = 0$ in $\mathbb{Z}_q$ if $r=0$ then $q=19$ therefore we can assume $r\neq 0$ if $s=0$ then $q$ is a divisor of $660$ therefore $q\in \{2,3,5,11\}$ so $s\neq 0$ and if $r=0$ then $q\in \{4,7,47\}$ you can check that $q\not = 47$ so we can assume $r,s,t\neq 0$.

Comment: oh! you can assume that $r=19$ because $q>19$.

Comment: @yanko The biggest prime divisor is  $408255160853$. The second biggest is $19$.

Comment: @Michael This is certainly *not* an answer to the question. Of course it is trivial to use modular arithmetic to find/verify the factor $19$ (esp. trivial here since $\,1316\equiv -600\pmod{19}).\ $ But that implies nothing at all about the question asked, viz. whether or not it has a larger factor below $10000$. **Please don't post a comment as an answer**

Comment: @Bill Dubuque I posted my answer because I thought that will help. If you'll post your solution  I'll delete my post. By the way, it's indeed, trivial, but I saw it during one minute!

Comment: @Michael You should repost your remark as a comment. That's one of the primary purposes of comments. Random observations that you speculate might  help are *not* answers!

Comment: @Bill Dubuque Why do you do it me? Post your solution and I'll delete my post.

Comment: @Michael Don't take it personally. It is generally the convention of this site that answers (and hints) need to show a clear way to solve the problem. Guesses, speculations or other observations are reserved for comments. I don't see any clear way to solve the problem from what you wrote, so it should not be posted as an answer (not even a start!) It is essential to maintain such high standards for answers, else it will be hard to separate true answers from other random comments.

Comment: @Bill Dubuque I am often getting similar things in inequalities. I don't do, which you are doing me.

Comment: @Michael I have no idea what your prior comment means (I have little familiarity with questions on inequalities since I rarely read them).

Comment: @Bill Dubuque I like inequalities, like you like the number theory. I understand you!